# Display different text everytime you call onclick function

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code where I am trying to pull users from my firebase database:

```
function pullFromDB(){
        usersRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
          function next_user(){
            for (user in snapshot.val().users){
              document.getElementById("users").innerHTML = user
            }
          }
```

So far it will return just one of the users as I believe it must be going through the whole users array and then putting the last name into the "users" element.
How can I iterate to the next item in the array and display a different name every time I click a button?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what's return from DB but first try the `console.log()` to see what's the type of result. This will give you the answer if you are working on array or other data type.

Then if it's an array, your code:

```
for (user in snapshot.val().users){
              document.getElementById("users").innerHTML = user
}
```

It iterates the whole array and `.innerHTML` puts `user` string as the last iteration. If you want to change it each time you click a button you need a variable that will contain inteager of index that's currently aplied to id="users".

Then for each click you need to increase the variable by one.
Here is an example of working with arrays in JS. http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_array_element

Answer (score 0):

Your are iterating through the whole array and only the last one is possible shown. You just need to assign an index and use it.

I don't know your remaining code, but by the given information, this should to the trick:

```
i = 0;

function pullFromDB(){
  usersRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    lastnames = Object.keys(snapshot.val().users); // get all keys, in your case the last names
    function next_user(){
      user = lastnames[i];
      document.getElementById("users").innerHTML = user;
      i++; // increase after click
      // when you want to access more information of the user, you can do it like this (as an example)
      // user_id = snapshot.val().users[user].id;
    }
```

Comment: this returns undefined maybe because it is a list of objects instead of an array.
when i do: `console.log(snapshot.val().users);` i get `Object {Mike: Object, Oli: Object, Pete: Object, Rich: Object, k: Object}`

but if i do: `console.log(snapshot.val().users[i]);` i get `undefined`

Comment: Okay, this explains a lot. I updated my answer accordingly. You need to get all last names first and can then iterate through them with them as an index.